# Find overlapping and non overlapping intervals in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a typical events table: events(id, start, end)

I want to chop them into intervals:

```
           I1    I2    I3     I4       I5
EVENT 1    <---|-----|----|-------->
EVENT 2              <----|--------|------->
EVENT 3        <-----|--->|
```

If I write my query like this I don't get non overlapping parts:

```
SELECT greatest(E1.start, E2.start) as O1, least(E1.end, E2.end) as O2
FROM events E1, events E2
WHERE E1.id <> E2.id
HAVING O1 < O2
```

The expected result result should contain 5 records like in the graphic above.

MySQL version 8+

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd0c84/7)

Comment: This is easier in MySQL 8+ die to use of window functions. So, which version are you using?

Comment: What precisely should be included in your results? For example, should each "piece" have the event id? Or, do you want 5 pieces or 9 pieces? [mre]

Comment: @MatBailie I want 5 pieces

Comment: Please read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE event (
  id      INT,
  start   INT, 
  end     INT
)
```

```
INSERT INTO
  event
VALUES
  (1, 1, 9),
  (2, 3, 7),
  (3, 2, 5)
```

```
WITH
  boundaries AS
(
  SELECT start FROM event
  UNION
  SELECT end   FROM event
),
  pieces AS
(
  SELECT
    start,
    LEAD(start)
      OVER (
        ORDER BY start
      )
        AS end
  FROM
    boundaries
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  pieces
WHERE
  end IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
  start
```

| start | end |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 7 | 9 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HF3g7oWz)